# Excel VBA - Floor on Column's Used Rows

Tags: vba, excel, floor

I am trying to convert the used range of a column to hourly data using floor.

As a function in Excel I have `=FLOOR(A2, "1:00")`

So *2016-07-01 07:59:59.0000000* would become *01-07/2016 7:00*

I would like to do this in VBA for just Column A where the first row is a header.  I guess I'd need to convert to dateTime afterwards to but haven't thought about that yet (shouldn't be difficult).

I have tried this:

```
.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) = _
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), "1:00")
```

But get wrong number of arguments error.

This:

```
.Range("A:A") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor("A:A", "1:00")
```

gives a type mismatch.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You will get circular reference error, If you try to enter a formula and reference the same cell.

Comment: You have to enter the formula in B2 which is Floor based on A2 Value

Comment: My Excel formula works as I am entering it in a different cell.  I would now like to use VBA instead to convert the the Date column.  Or even create a new one, that would be fine.

Comment: You are putting the VBA in column A as well - do you want to overwrite the original values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`WorksheetFunction.Floor` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Floor) in VBA is a little different from the worksheets `=Floor` function:

```
 WorksheetFunction.Floor(Arg1, Arg2)
```

Both arguments `Arg1` and `Arg2` need to be of the type `double`.

So you will need to use `1/24` instead of `"1:00"` (which is the same because 1 hour is 1/24 of a day) and a value `.Cells(i, "A").Value` instead of a cell reference name `"A:A"`.
Also you will need a loop to achieve it for every used cell in the whole column A.

```
Option Explicit 'First line at your module ensures you declare any variables

Public Sub FloorFormat()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Your sheet name here
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow 'do the following for all used rows in column A
            .Cells(i, "A").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(.Cells(i, "A").Value, 1 / 24)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thakn you for the background info on the method itself @peh.  I've kind of struggled to find that myself.  I was beginning to think that a loop might be required.  I guess this is standard practice when attempting to work on columns with any function.  I'll try this out and mark as correct once I've confirmed.

Comment: Perfect.  I changed i value to 2 so it ignored the header in row 1.